# FIRMessaging using another FIRApp

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an Pod for my internal projects using Firebase Messaging. I want to use FIRMessaging and FIRInstanceID with another FIRApp, like I can do with FIRDatabase or FIRAuth, for example:

```
FIRApp.configure(withName: "Library", options: appOptions!)
var auth = FIRAuth(app: FIRApp.init(named: "Library")!)
var db = FIRDatabase.database(app: FIRApp.init(named: "Library")!)
```

It's possible? How can I implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use FCM with projects other than the default one. FCM generates tokens based on the project's sender ID. So if you want to generate IID tokens that correspond to a project other than the default project then you need to use the [tokenWithAuthorizedEntity](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseinstanceid/api/reference/Classes/FIRInstanceID#/c:objc(cs)FIRInstanceID(im)tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:scope:options:handler:) function to generate the token.

Note thought that you will have to disable swizzling since when swizzling is turned on the default project will be used.

Your flow should be something like:

- Disable Swizzling
- Register for remote notifications
- Retrieve the APNs token, and call setApnsToken
- Generate token with tokenWithAuthorizedEntity
- Send messages from project with sender ID used in tokenWithAuthorizedEntity

Comment: Hi @arthur-thompson, thanks for your help. I tried to implement as you said, but I'm receiving this error: Optional(Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1002 "(null)" in FIRInstanceIDTokenHandler. I tried to find what this error means, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: I believe that may be one of the log messages that we need to clean up. Are you able to generate an IID token? If so then you should be able to ignore this, we are working on cleaning up the unnecessary logs. If not respond here and we can dig further.

Comment: unfortunately i didn't receive the IID Token. I receive the above error in return of tokenWithAuthorizedEntity.

Comment: Could you confirm that the APNs certs have been added to the project with the sender ID that you are trying to get the token for?

Comment: Yes, the APNS certs are added to the project because when I configure the Library Firebase Project as the default FIRApp in my app, everything works correctly.

Comment: Arthur, I found the problem: In the tokenWithAuthorizedEntity, I need to fill options with "apns_token" and "apns_sandbox" (Because I found the meaning for error code 1002 in GGLInstanceID.h) . I was sending only "apns_token" in options.Thanks for your help

Comment: I see, that is indeed correct, we need to make these requirements clearer. Thanks for working through this.